# Rails access uploaded file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, file, file-upload, carrierwave

I'm building a site on rails and backbone. On the front end I have a simple form:

```
<form action="/api/users" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="profile_image" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="put">
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= csrf_token %>">
</form>
```

When I post this form and print `params[:profile_image]` from my `UsersController` the line

`logger.debug params[:profile_image].class` 
just returns
`String`.

Where's the file?

For what it's worth, I'm using carrierwave, but don't want to mount an uploader. I would just like to pass a file to `myUploader.store!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `enctype` on your form in order to submit files. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Example

```
<form action="/api/users" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```